# Como usar MYSQL com Case ou IF

Tags: sql-update

Essa é com CASE que não funciona, a ideia é simples todos os dias os treinos dos jogadores são resetados a 15, CASO o jogador seja VIP, ou seja tenha "tempoVIP" MENOR que a data atual, ele tem apenas 15 Treinos, caso não ele teria 25, eu tentei de suas formas com Case (não deu certo) e if (Tambem não), alguem sabe como fazer funcionar?

`` UPDATE `_personagens` SET `treinos_restantes`= CASE  WHEN (tempoVip<CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN "15" ELSE "25" END ``

`` UPDATE `_personagens`  SET `treinos_restantes`=IF((tempoVip<CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 15, 25) WHERE Id>0 ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `UPDATE` pode ser utilizado com `WHERE`.

```
UPDATE `_personagens` SET `treinos_restantes` = "XX" WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() >= `tempoVip`;
UPDATE `_personagens` SET `treinos_restantes` = "XX" WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() <= `tempoVip`;
```

Comment: A Ação executa mas não altera as linhas onde o Tempo Vip é Maior, o CURRENT_TIMESTAMP é a melhor opção?

Comment: ```UPDATE `_personagens` SET `treinos_restantes` = "15" WHERE 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) >= `tempoVip`
UPDATE `_personagens` SET `treinos_restantes` = "25" WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) <= `tempoVip` ```

Funcionou porque era UNIX! Valeu